# Wedderburn Ring: Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the book A Course in Ring Theory by Donald Passman, the author defines:

> A ring $R$ (may be non-commutative, with unity $1$) is called right Wedderburn ring if $R$ as right $R$-module is Artinian and it has no non-zero nilpotent ideal.

Now Wedderburn's work on structure of (non-commutative) rings seems to be started before Emil Artin. So, what was original definition of Wedderburn ring? Is it the same as above?

The above definition combines two very different non-related facts - being Artinian and having no  non-zero nilpotent ideals. Thus, is seems that Wedderburn, if he has introduced these rings, may not have defined it in above way.

What is the motivation to define Wedderburn rings in above way?

Answer (score 1):

This would be the source to pay attention to

> Wedderburn, JH Maclagan. "On hypercomplex numbers." Proceedings of the London Mathematical Society 2.1 (1908): 77-118.

On page 78,

> It is assumed throughout that a finite basis can be chosen for any algebra which is under discussion, that is, we suppose that it is always possible to
> find a finite number of elements of the algebra which are linearly independent with regard to some given field, and are such that any other
> number of the algebra can be linearly expressed in terms of them.

So Wedderburn's original study was of finite dimensional semisimple algebras.  No doubt later on, with the rise of chain conditions later in the century, it was later seen that the minimum condition on right ideals would also suffice.